# Create app accessible before keylock

Tags: android-widget

Is it possible to create an app that is accessible BEFORE the keylock? Like an small icon is pressed beside [Emergency Call] and app pops up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add an icon like that without modifying the Android OS. You can add a lock screen widget, however.

Lock screen widgets were added in Android 4.2, take a look at official [google docs](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#Lockscreen). On Android 4.0+ there is support for media player control from the lock screen, look for "Remote control client" [here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0.html#api).

Comment: So if i understand correctly, this app has to include an lockscreen app + initial app?

Thanks for answear :)